# To delete all the character from a filename before a matching keyword is found using shell script one liner

Tags: linux, shell

I have lots of files with below formats

```
2022-01-04_09-14-07_1003-pbx72900a45_0349821623_0333947635_0027333947635_cloud.mp3
2022-01-04_09-03-18__27829201595_0027349821623__cloud.-1641279798.89196.mp3
```

I want to remove all the character before the word cloud for e.g

```
cloud.mp3
cloud.-1641279798.89196.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use shell parameter expansion to remove the longest string from the start that matches `*cloud` and then prepend "cloud" back to it:

```sh
for file in ./*cloud*.mp3
do
  mv -- "$file" cloud"${file#*cloud}"
done
```

You can adjust the wildcard pattern `./*cloud*.mp3` as needed. This doesn't check for clobbering of filenames.